# How to use if with grep -x

Tags: linux, bash, grep

This is my code:

```
if grep -x $idle | grep -x $dead | grep -x $busy ./Event.log
 then 
   echo " Events are running Successfully" >> ./Event.log
 else 
   echo "One or more Events are down. Check the log and restart the Events." >> ./Event.log
fi
```

I am getting the below error:

```
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 1.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 0.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open 0.
```

Even when the `if` condition is satisfied it goes to the `else` block.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Command `grep` takes two arguments: *pattern* and *file*. The file can be omitted if input is connected to stdin with pipe `|` or redirection `<`. In you examples this is not the case so the first `grep` doesn't know where to look for pattern. You would need to write instead:

```
grep -x $idle Event.log | grep -x $dead | grep -x $busy
```

Notice, that second and third `grep`s  doesn't need file argument as they read from pipe.

However in your case I guess that you rather want to look for three alternative strings. Thus you can use alternative operator `|` with `grep -E` or `\|` without `-E`, eg:

```
if grep -x "$idle\|$dead\|$busy" ./Event.log >/dev/null
    then
    echo " Events are running Successfully" >> ./Event.log
else
    echo "One or more Events are down. Check the log and restart the Events." >> ./Event.log
fi
```

Comment: And probably you want to revert the logic - if any of these strings are found then echo "events are down", if not found "events are running successfully".

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to quote the regex (to avoid shell word splitting rules), disable options (to avoid leading hyphens in regex from being treated as options to `grep`), and formally indicate that stdin is being grepped.

```
$ x="hi there"; (echo hi there; echo bye there) | grep -- "$x" -
hi there
```

If you only need the result for the test condition, the `-q` option to `grep` may also be relevant.